# thinkorswim installer too small

Tags: command-line, display-resolution, dpi

I am attempting to install [thinkorswim](https://www.tdameritrade.com/tools-and-platforms/thinkorswim/desktop/download.page) on Ubuntu 18.04. I have followed their installation instructions listed [here](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/faq/technical#q_011111111111111114).

They are as follows:

> **How do I install Zulu OpenJDK in order to install thinkorswim on Linux Operating Systems?**
>
> 1. Log in as root or use sudo in a terminal window.
> 2. Import Azul's public key:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0xB1998361219BD9C9
>    ```
> 3. Add the Azul package to the APT repository for Ubuntu/Linux Mint:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable main'
>    ```
> 4. Update the information about available packages:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get update
>    ```
> 5. Install Zulu by using the following command for Ubuntu/Linux Mint/Debian (APT)
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install zulu-8
>    ```
> 6. Change Default Java to Zulu 8 via the following command, it should list the installed java versions with a corresponding number to the
>      left
>
>    ```
>    sudo update-alternatives --config java
>    sudo update-alternatives --config javac
>    ```
>
>    **How do I install thinkorswim on Linux Operating Systems?**
> 7. Navigate to downloads and right click `thinkorswim_installer.sh`, select "Properties”
> 8. Select the "Permissions" tab, and make sure "Allow executing file as program" is selected
> 9. Close the window
> 10. Double click `thinkorswim_installer.sh`

I've followed these instructions and managed to start the installer, but I am unable to accept the terms of the License Agreement because the the installer window is too small.

[image: Picture of thinkorswim installer.]

I've tried changing the resolution and zoom of my display, but I haven't been able to fix the issue. How can I scale the installer so I can see the full window?

Comment: You can try to do the following: move mouse focus to the Setup window, then press `<Tab>` key to highlight possible checkmark and hit `<Space>`, then click Next button.

Comment: I have the same problem, @N0rbert 's comment didn't help me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue on my system by going to Settings -> Displays -> Scale = 100% -> Apply

It appears that having a scale other than 100% will cause the installer to not work properly.